# What is the probability that the polynomial has real roots?

Tags: probability, integration

The variables $a$, $b$ and $c$ are iid random variables with exponential distribution with common parameter $1$. What is the probability that the polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$ has real roots?

My attempt:

$\Pr[ax^2+bx+c\;\text{has real roots}]=\Pr[b^2-4ac\geqslant0]=\Pr[b\geqslant2\sqrt{ac}\;\text{or}\;b\leqslant-2\sqrt{ac}]=\Pr[b\geqslant2\sqrt{ac}]=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\int_{2\sqrt{ac}}^\infty f_{a,b,c}(a,b,c)dadbdc$

Am I right? How can I continue?

Comment: You're right, and I don't see how you can continue. Since the exponential distribution has nice properties with respect to addition, not multiplication of the variable, I would have expected this to give a nice result if the logarithms of the parameters had been thus distributed. Do you have reasons to expect this to have a closed-form solution?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In fact this question came from [this book](https://books.google.ca/books?id=CLtDhblwWEgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=stochastic+geometry+for+wireless+networks&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAWoVChMIxtimwO-9yAIVgjU-Ch248wvz#v=onepage&q&f=true) and now I am confused Did I understand the question wrong? The question is Problem 1.6 page 8 in google books. In this problem, the question is to prove that the probability is in fact equal to $1/3$.

Comment: Your understanding of the question was correct; it turns out that the triple integration can be performed after all. By the way, $\mathrm db$ should come first in your triple integral, corresponding to the limits on the integral signs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align}
\mathsf P\left(a\gt \frac{b^2}{4c}\right)
&=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\int_{\frac{b^2}{4c}}^\infty\exp(-a-b-c)\,\mathrm da\,\mathrm db\,\mathrm dc\\
&=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\exp\left(-\frac{b^2}{4c}-b-c\right)\mathrm db\,\mathrm dc\\
&=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty c\exp\left(-\frac{s^2}4c-sc-c\right)\mathrm ds\,\mathrm dc\\
&=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty c\exp\left(-\left(\frac s2+1\right)^2c\right)\mathrm dc\,\mathrm ds\\
&=\int_0^\infty\left(\frac s2+1\right)^{-4}\,\mathrm ds\\
&=16\int_2^\infty s^{-4}\,\mathrm ds\\
&=\frac23
\end{align}

(where I used the substitution $b=sc$), so the desired probability is $\frac13$. As I wrote in a comment, I'm surprised that this has such a nice closed form, even more so that the probability is $\frac13$, which cries out for a solution with a transformation to three symmetric quantities of which one must be the greatest; I've posted a new question about this: [Symmetric proof for the probability of real roots of a quadratic with exponentially distributed parameters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477779).